# In Visual Studio 2017, asp.net web site, I cannot add 64 bit DLLs and therefore cannot compile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, iis-7.5

We have a web-site (not web-application) running on IIS 7.5. The site uses our own in-house domain specific libraries (DLLs). The site compiles as expected from within the IDE when we use the 32 bit version of these libraries, and runs as expected on the site's web-server.

But, when we use the 64 bit versions of our in-house libraries, which use 64 bit Oracle Client Drivers (one DLL), the IDE (VS 2017) does not even list/reference our libraries from within References Section of the site, and therefore cannot compile resulting in 'too many errors'. On the other hand, the site runs well and as expected on the site's server (because we set the application pool's Enable 32-bit applications = false).

Therefore, although the site compiles and runs as expected on the server, we cannot debug it from within Visual Studio because we cannot reference our in-house 64 bit libraries (which use 64 bit Oracle Drivers).

I have scoured the web to find a way to select the target platform from within Visual Studio but could not find one as Any-CPU is the only option available. VS seems to automatically target 32-bit and therefore does not recognise the 64-bit-only DLLs.